Parameter pack and perfect forwarding
I just wrote following simple code but it doesnt compile:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Obj{
public:
    std::string name = "Name";
    std::string l_name = "LastName";
    
    template<typename P>
    Obj(P&& param): name{std::forward<P>(param)} { }
    
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Obj& obj);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Obj& obj) {
    os << obj.name << ":" << obj.l_name;
    return os;
}


void print() {
    std::cout << "}";
}

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
void print(T param, Args... args) {
    std::size_t count = sizeof...(args);
    std::cout << param;
    if ( count != 0 ) {
        std::cout << ",";
    }
    print(args...);
}

template<typename... Args>
void run(Args... args) {
    std::cout << "{";
    print(args...);
}

int main() {
    Obj obj{"obj"};
    run("1", "2", 1.3, std::string{"Some Message"}, obj);
    
    return 0;
}

I just used simple parameter pack and perfect forwarding example but gives following error:
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Obj::Obj(P&&) [with P = Obj&]’:
main.cpp:49:8:   required from here
main.cpp:12:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string::basic_string()’
   12 |     Obj(P&& param): name{std::forward<P>(param)} {
...

If i dont use the obj paramater in the run function, the example works as expected.

print/run can be simplified with C++17 Demo.

@Jarod42 nice edit, thanks

@Jarod42 will writing the statement this way cause an error? ((std::cout << sep << args, sep= ", "), ...);   I just removed one parentheses.

I prefer to be safe with some operator precedencies.

Unfortunately
template<typename P>
Obj(P&& param): name{std::forward<P>(param)} { }

is too greedy, and catch Obj(Obj&) (for which it is wrong).
You might SFINAE that constructor,
template<typename P>
requires (std::is_constructible_v<std::string, P>)
Obj(P&& param): name{std::forward<P>(param)} { }

Demo
or add extra overloads
Obj(Obj&&) = default;
Obj(Obj&) = default; // To fix the issue
Obj(const Obj&) = default;

Demo
or even simpler, as you don't need template here:
explicit Obj(std::string name): name{std::move(name)} { }

Demo

is it okey also if i define template like this => template<typename P, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<P, Obj&>>>

There are several ways to SFINAE, std::enable_if is pre-C++20. Condition might be adapted to your needs.

The problem is that the constructor template
template<typename P>
Obj(P&& param)

would accept an Obj lvalue.
Obj still has an implicitly-defined copy constructor and move constructor, but those have the signatures Obj(const Obj&) and Obj(Obj&&) respectively, so they lose in overload resolution when an lvalue of type Obj is passed.
You can have a forwarding constructor that takes P&&, but this needs to be properly constrained.
For example, std::tuple has a constructor  that takes any UTypes&&..., but this is constrained to not accept a std::tuple so that the copy/move constructors always win.
In C++20 and upwards, you could write
template<typename P>
  requires !std::convertible_to<P&&, Obj>
Obj(P&& param)

In older versions, you could use std::enable_if instead.
You can also avoid the use of templates entirely here by making a constructor:
Obj(std::string&& param) : name(std::move(param)) { }

Note that you could also take a std::string by value, but this is commonly advised against (see CppCoreGuidelines F.18: For “will-move-from” parameters, pass by X&& and std::move the parameter).
